# Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsMyketRelease ...]

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

I updated Android to version 3.2. Now when I want to Build, or clean or sync project, the following error dispatch:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: 
Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsMyketRelease, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@70c73c24] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:179)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:164)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
```

build.Gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
  }
}
```

Gradle-Wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

Update Gradle to latest version manually.

Replace the following line of Gradle-wrapper.propperties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be stable channel? How do they let things like that through... thanks

Comment: No. This problem happened in Android 3.2 Stable for me.